# Vertically center a caption on hover

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment, caption

Is it possible to vertically center a caption on hover using the following code? I know I could add a div surrounding the figcaption tag to do an overlay, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do the same without adding more HTML code.

HTML:

```
<figure class="caption">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
    <figcaption class="caption-text">Some text</figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
.caption {
    position: relative;
}

.caption img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

.caption-text {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.caption:hover .caption-text {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.7);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Flexbox** on `.caption-text`

```css
.caption {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.caption img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}

.caption-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.caption:hover .caption-text {
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.7);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure class="caption">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
   <figcaption class="caption-text">Some text</figcaption>
</figure>
```